# What is the best technique I can use to encrypt inner nodes in B+tree?

Tags: encryption

I'am working on searchable encryption.

First I create an index for a set of files. The index is B+ tree. The leaf of this tree is a bloom filter which represents the words in each file. Each bloom filter represents one file. Inner nodes represent XOR of these leaf nodes.

Last but not least: to encrypt this tree, I'ld like to encrypt each leaf node separately, but I'm confused which techniqe should be used to encrypt the inner nodes – while keeping it easy to do searches in this tree. What is the best technique I can use to encrypt inner nodes in B+tree?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know your scheme, so we cannot say which technique is better for you, but in most earlier schemes that use binary vector (or any integer vector) for store information, **Secure Inner Product** is most used tools for encrypting! And it's useful for searching in some condition and depend on search construction.

P.S. Why you using *bloom filter* that has *false positive* issue?
I'm working on SE too.